# implementing many-to-many relationship with Zend\Form and Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a `Zend\Form` and corresponding Doctrine entity class where the entity as a `ManyToMany` relationship with another entity. More precisely, the user needs to be able to choose one or more names from a data table containing 12,000 names -- far too many for a normal SELECT element.

In an earlier iteration of this project, which used ZF1, I had a `MultiSelect` element, with zero options, that I simply never rendered. Instead I made an autocompletion text field with JQueryUI for dynamically inserting the human-readable names and the ids as hidden elements. Worked great.

I have looked at `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` but the docs say you can't update it with fewer elements than you started out with -- that is, if at update-form hydration time you have 2 whatevers, you have to submit at least 2 whatevers. That won't do.

Elsewhere I am happily using `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect` but it doesn't seem like the right choice for this case.

Before I go off and try to use the same technique I used with ZF1 I'd be delighted if anyone could give me a better idea.

Comment: If you never rendered, then how did you get the values and ids for validating the input into your JQueryUI in your previous solution?

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand.  My form had a jquery ui autocompletion text field. Its 'select' callback added DOM elements -- hidden row id, human-friendly text value, a button for removing both. The array of ids thus added would get posted. On the server side I checked referential integrity, if that's what you mean. When the form was loaded for update rather than create, I'd put the data in the view and use a helper to print the array of already-existing ids/values, rather than Javascript. Submitting this array satisfied the unrendered element's validators -- Zend_Form was none the wiser.

Comment: If you don't get any answers that satisfy your needs, then I think it would be great if you answer you own question with your previous JQueryUI solution. It seems pretty smart to me and it might help others...

Comment: I might as well. :-) I am also struggling as a noob with Doctrine and DQL does not fit what I'm doing very well. plain old SQL sometimes has its virtues. I might compromise by pulling the DBAL thing out of the Entity Manager and working with that. When I come up with something not too embarassing, I will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer: there is no exotic, secret knowledge. Use autocompletion and a database as you would with any other tools/libraries.

To describe my use-case a little: users submit requests for an interpreter for a future court proceeding. They have to provide the name(s) of the defendant(s), among other data (e.g., language). There are over 12K such names already in our database and we re-use recurring names (IOW, the entity represents a person's proper name rather than a person).

Now for some code excerpts. In the front end, the view script:

```
<?php 
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/dev-requests/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/dev-requests/js/defts.js');
// stuff omitted...
// within the form:
// $element is a \Zend\Form\Element\Select with attribute 'multiple' => 'multiple', zero options,
// and it's hidden via css because no one needs to see it
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="<?=$element->getName()?>"><?=$element->getLabel()?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"><?= $this->formElement($element)?><?= $this->formElementErrors($element) ?>
    <?php if ($this->defendants): 
    // if we are an update (as opposed to create) action, our controller's updateAction 
    // will have set $this->defendants to a (possibly empty) array of 'defendantName' entities
    foreach($this->defendants as $deft): ?>
        <div id="deft-div-<?=$deft->getDeftId()?>"><span class="remove-div"><a href="#">[x]</a></span> 
            <?=$deft->getFullname()?>
            <input value="<?=$deft->getDeftId()?>" name="request-fieldset[defendantNames][]" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some Javascript from `defts.js`, inside our document.ready() callback:

```
// the autocomplete textfield itself
$('#deft-select').after(
    $('<input>').attr({id:'deftname-autocomplete',size:25})
);
// for deleting a name from the form
($('form').on('click','span.remove-div',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().slideUp(function(){$(this).remove();});
}));

$('#deftname-autocomplete').autocomplete({

    source : '/dev-requests/defendants/autocomplete',
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        // add a human-readable label and hidden form element
        $(this).val('');
        var elementName = $('#deft-select').attr('name');
        var deftName = ui.item.label;
        var deft_id  = ui.item.value;
        if ($( '#deft-div-'+ deft_id ).length) {
            return false; // already exists
        }
        var div = $(this).closest('div');
        div.append(
            $('<div/>').attr({id: "deft-div-"+ deft_id})
                .html([
                    '<span class="remove-div"><a href="#">[x]</a></span> ' + deftName,
                    $('<input/>').attr({type:'hidden',name:elementName}).val(deft_id)
                ])
        );
        return false;
    }

});
```

In our controller:

```
 public function autocompleteAction()
{

    $term = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('term');
    if (! $term) { return false; }

    /**
     * @var $em Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('entity-manager');
    /**
     * @var $repo Application\Entity\DefendantNameRepository
     */
    $repo = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\DefendantName');

    $data = json_encode($repo->autocomplete($term));
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaders(['Content-type'=>'application/json;charset=UTF-8']);
    return $response->setContent($data);
}
```

In our custom Doctrine repository, Application\Entity\DefendantNameRepository:

```
/**
* return array of value/label for autocompletion via xhr
* @param string $term name 
* @param int limit max number of records to return
*  
* $term is expected to be proper name in the format la[stname][,f[irstname]] 
*/

public function autocomplete($term, $limit = 20) {

    /**
     * @var $connection Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    list($lastname,$firstname) = $this->parseName($term);
    if (! strstr($lastname,'-')) {
        $where = 'lastname LIKE '.$connection->quote("$lastname%");
    } else {
        // they frequently insert gratuitous hyphens between the 
        // paternal and maternal surnames of Spanish-speaking people
        $lastname = str_replace('-','( |-)',$lastname);
        $where = 'lastname REGEXP '.$connection->quote("^$lastname");
    }
    if ($firstname) {
        $where .= " AND firstname LIKE ".$connection->quote("$firstname%");
    } else {
        $where .= " AND firstname <> '' "; // some old records have no firstname, but we don't like that
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT(lastname, ", ",firstname) AS label, deft_id AS value 
            FROM deft_names WHERE '.$where . " ORDER BY lastname, firstname LIMIT $limit ";
    return $connection->fetchAll($sql);
}
```

...and this little helper, elsewhere in our repository:

```
/**
 * parses first and last names out of $name. expected format is
 * la[stname][,f[irstname]] 
 * @param string $name
 * @return array ($lastname, $firstname)
 */
public function parseName($name) {

    $name = preg_split('/ *, */',trim($name),2,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if (2 == sizeof($name)) {
        list($last, $first) = $name;
    } else {
        $last = $name[0];
        $first = false;
    }
    return array($last,$first);
}
```

The class definition Application\Entity\DefendantName is straightforward and omitted for brevity.

Still to do:  add a search button thingy to the right of our autocompleting text element for them to click when they get no autocompletion matches so we can tell them "sorry, no matching records found." And -- though this is tangential to the original question -- provide a way for them to submit names we've never heard of.

Answer (score 0):

All I can come up with for now is to use a HTML5 pattern (regex) validator. But I would say this is much less user friendly then you current solution. I am also very doubtful about whether a regex can handle 12000 names as a constraint. It sounds like a bad idea to be honest.

You could maybe enhance your current solution with this by restricting to alphabetic characters:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]*" placeholder="Write a valid name">
```

Comment: thanks -- but validation isn't the part I'm concerned about. the input data is gonna come from my database, and will have passed input validation to get there -- or else, if they cleverly try to input something else, it will throw a foreign key constraint exception.